# hiding functions in C

Tags: c, linux, ld-preload

I have application that has a function f1  `void f1 ()`

In addition, I have a library that I load using `LD_PRELOAD`.

The library has several code files and several header file, and it compiled to .so file.

On of the header files also uses a function named `f1` with same signature as above.
The latest `f1` is used only in the library. (I can not change it to static method)

The problem is that when I load the library (using `LD_PRELOAD`) `f1` from the library overrides `f1` of the application.

Is there a way to configure `f1` of the library to be visible only to the library?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just rename one of the function declarations? I'm guessing this is in an existing codebase which might be why you can't

Answer (score 6):

If you can modify the header files at all, make the function `static` to make it visible only in that compilation unit, or mark it with `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` (GCC only) to make it visible only in that library:

```
__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden"))) void f1();
```

Comment: Is `__attribute__ ((visibility ("hidden")))` macro that replace with static **?** or how does it works?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: No, that attribute marks a symbol as having hidden visibility. It is visible only *within that shared library* (kind of like the opposite of Win32 `DLLEXPORT`). The hidden visibility attribute is passed to and understood by the linker (as opposed to `static`, which makes a symbol basically *invisible* to the linker).

Answer (score 3):

You could also compile your library with [-fvisibility=hidden](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) and use explicit `__attribute__ ((visibility ("default")))` for the few functions of your library which needs to be visible.